# Computer networks-Subnet mask

Tags: networking

Is **255.0.255.0** a subnet mask? 
If yes, then why?
The reason I thought is its a subnet mask of either class A(N.H.H.H) or class B (N.N.H.H). If there are 255 Network thrn there should be 255 hosts. Please correct me of I am wrong. I am learning the basics of computer networks

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (probably before you were born) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use classes. Any discussion about network classes is purely historical. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains IPv4 addressing, and there is a section about network classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 4631, §3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632#section-3.1) states that (emphasis mine)

> a [subnet] prefix [...] describes the number of **significant bits**

So, subnet masks must be a contiguous sequence of ones, and 255.0.255.0 is not a valid subnet mask.

Note that this RFC introduced CIDR, which replaced the old style of Class A/B/C addressing.

This is a potential duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/979915/are-subnets-always-contiguous-1s

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not a subnet mask. because of my knowledge there are 255.0.0.0 for class A; 255.255.0.0 for class B; 255.255.255.0 for class C

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (probably before you were born) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use classes. Any discussion about network classes is purely historical. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains IPv4 addressing, and there is a section about network classes.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically it can be used as a subnet mask but in practical situation subnet mask have 
all 1's continuously followed by all 0's.  the reason why it can be theoretically be implemented because

no of 1's =NID +SID
no of 0's =HID

in practical situation it will make the computation much more complex